# Reflection - how to compare between list of types

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, comparison

I've a list of instances of various types (all of this types derive from a supertype). I need to get a sublist that includes only the instances that are of certain types or derived. A simplified example can be:

```
class Program
{
    private class A { }
    private class B : A { }
    private class C : A { }
    private class D : C { }

    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        D d = new D();

        var typesToHave = new List<Type>();
        typesToHave.Add(typeof(C));

        var result = new List<A>();
        if (typesToHave.Any(t => b.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(t)))
            result.Add(b);
        if (typesToHave.Any(t => c.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(t)))
            result.Add(c);
        if (typesToHave.Any(t => d.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(t)))
            result.Add(d);

    }
}
```

What I'm expecting to have here is a list with `c` and `d` but it returns nothing.

Also (but it is secondary) I can't figure out why I can't use the `is` or `as` operator in the lambda expression, like:

```
if (typesToHave.Any(t => d is t))
```

How can I have a list with `c` and `d` in the example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the parameters wrong. [IsInstanceOfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires an instance as parameter where as you pass `Type`.

Following should work.

```
if (typesToHave.Any(t => t.IsInstanceOfType(d)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IsAssignableFrom`

```
if (typesToHave.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(d.GetType()))
```

In order to use `is` or `as` operator you need to supply a `Type` name.Not a type instance, that's how those operators work.For example:

```
var list = new List<int>();
var ie = list as IEnumerable<int>;
```

Comment: Yes this works, surprisingly VS is suggesting me to rewrite the `IsAssignableFrom` to `IsInstanceOfType`..Why can this works and the opposite not? And why I cannot use the `is` operator? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is also an alternative that works pretty good:

```
if (typesToHave.Any(t => b.GetType().IsSubclassOf(t) || b.GetType() == t))
    result.Add(b);
if (typesToHave.Any(t => c.GetType().IsSubclassOf(t) || c.GetType() == t))
    result.Add(c);
if (typesToHave.Any(t => d.GetType().IsSubclassOf(t) || d.GetType() == t))
    result.Add(d);
```

Comment: does this work also for multi-nested types? example: `d.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(A))`?

Comment: nevermind, I've checked and it works, thank you for your solution